# Finding Specific text in body and removing it via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating HTML and ASPX file via C# code in APX everything works fine but in HTML page  it appends the aspx tag which shows as plain text in body. i want to remove any text in body that starts with `<%` and ends with `%>`

### here is the generated html

```
<body>
   <center>
 <%String action = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority+"/ABC/Data/a12.aspx" ; %>
     <div>
        <form>
          // some input fields and a submit button
        </form>
     </div>
   </center>
</body>
```

I have tried

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace( <%String action = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority+"/ABC/Data/a12.aspx" ; %>, "");
```

but didn't work for me, as the generated aspx tag is not same all the time..

Comment: Is that **actually** the generated html?

Comment: @hindmost: look at the updated question, now it portraits the original html file

Comment: I believe that's the original source file (aspx), but not the generated html (on client-side)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
    .replace( <%String action = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority+"/ABC/Data/a12.aspx" ; %>, "");
```

You are: not using a string as the first argument, this is invalid.

I would suggest you to use a regex, that matches <% [anything] %>.

Like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
    .replace(/<%.*%>/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

By using regular expression, I guess this should give what you need:

```
<script>
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(<%).*(%>)/ig, '');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Render Blocks shouldn't be rendered in HTML pages unless you're using them wrong. Try to modify your markup as follows:

```
<body>
   <center>
     <div>
        <form action='<%= "http://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/ABC/Data/a12.aspx" %>'>
          // some input fields and a submit button
        </form>
     </div>
   </center>
</body>
```